# Multiple radio buttons as filters

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

#### Problem

I am trying to create a double filter, where you can combine filters from multiple categories. For example, first category of filters are years, and the second one types of media. I want to make so that you can filter only through the years, media type or both year x type of media (Music form the 1960s). Also, I'm trying to keep selected filters highlighted, somehow so you can keep track of which ones are active (I tried to make them bold, and it works for first set of filters, but fails for the second. How do I solve this problem?

#### Codepen

https://codepen.io/erutuf/pen/ZPwdBq

#### Attempt

```js
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 37vw;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.btn:hover {}

.btn.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.content {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer" align="center" style="line-height: 20pt">
  <!-- <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>   Show ALL -->
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('ShowAll')">Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('1950')">1950</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('1960')">1960</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('1970')">1970</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="myBtnContainer" align="center" style="line-height: 20pt">
  <!-- <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>   Show ALL -->
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('AllMedia')">All Media</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Movies')">Movies</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Music')">Music</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('Newspapers')">Newspapers</button>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="filterDiv AllShapes ShowAll 1950 Newspapers">
  <div class="content">
    1950 Newspapers Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filterDiv AllShapes ShowAll 1960 Music">
  <div class="content">
    1960 Music Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filterDiv AllShapes ShowAll 1960 Newspapers">
  <div class="content">
    1960 Newspapers Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between "Show all colors" and "Show all shapes" buttons?

Comment: Bok Roko :) Sorry my bad, I used wrong filter-words for the example, I will change it now. But the idea is the first category encompass the possible filters from the second / the second row of filters are basically subcategories. Give me a sec i will fix the question

Comment: ok sorry again, fixed it. hope it is more clear now

Comment: Why don't you use `radio` buttons? `name="y"` (for years) and `name="t"` (for type) That way you could simply go for `this.checked` boolean instead of messing with classes...

Comment: yeah, I know radio would be the best way to go, i managed to do that with the radios, but i wanted to try with buttons simply bc of the aesthetics. so you think it would be too complicated to do it this way?

Comment: You can do it with buttons too, yeah, but you can also do it using styled `<label>` and hidden radio buttons. I'll try to make an example with buttons, stay tuned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `<label>` and `type="radio"` inputs.
You can style the inner `<i>` element, adjacent (`+`) to the `:checked` input.

Store the filter references (*props*) into a `data-filterable="value1 value2 valueZ"` **space delimited.**

The trick is to:

- on *change* event, get the **checked inputs values** as Array.
- **Hide** all elements (add a `.is-hidden` class)
- get a filtered subset of element to **show** - based on whether all the checked values are present in the `data-filterable` *props* (also as array).

**The below example will work for any number of filter-sets:**

```js
const el_filters = document.querySelectorAll('[name="year"], [name="type"]'),
  el_filterable = document.querySelectorAll('[data-filterable]');

const applyFilter = () => {

  // Filter checked inputs
  const el_checked = [...el_filters].filter(el => el.checked && el.value);
  
  // Collect checked inputs values to array
  const filters = [...el_checked].map(el => el.value);
  
  // Get elements to filter
  const el_filtered = [...el_filterable].filter(el => {
    const props = el.getAttribute('data-filterable').trim().split(/\s+/);
    return filters.every(fi => props.includes(fi))
  });

  // Hide all
  el_filterable.forEach(el => el.classList.add('is-hidden'));

  // Show filtered
  el_filtered.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('is-hidden'));
}

// Assign event listener
el_filters.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', applyFilter));
// Init
applyFilter();
```

```css
/* FILTER INPUTS */

.filterInputs {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.filterInputs input {
  display: none;
}

.filterInputs label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none; /* prevent highlight */
}

.filterInputs i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #0bf;
  z-index: -1;
}

.filterInputs input:checked + i {
  background: #0bf;
}


/* HELPER CLASSES */

.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterInputs">
  <label><input type="radio" name="year" value="" checked><i></i>All years</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="year" value="1950"><i></i>1950</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="year" value="1960"><i></i>1960</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="year" value="1970"><i></i>1970</label>
</div>

<div class="filterInputs">
  <label><input type="radio" name="type" value=""><i></i>All types</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="movies"><i></i>Movies</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="music" checked><i></i>Music</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="type" value="newspapers"><i></i>Newspapers</label>
</div>

<div data-filterable="1950 newspapers">1950 Newspapers</div>
<div data-filterable="1960 music">1960 Music</div>
<div data-filterable="1960 newspapers">1960 Newspapers</div>
```

Comment: i'm trying to figure out which line of js forces to show all the results by default at first? i want to make so the first thing it shows are already some filtered divs and not all of them

Comment: @erutuf edited my answer. Simply set the `checked` attribute in HTML to the desired element, and init the JS function `applyFilter()` That's all it takes.

Comment: sorry, my bad, when i c/p js code i somehow left out the init so the checked attribute wasn't working ‍♀️ thank you!

Comment: @erutuf no, it's not your bad, I added the *Init example* `applyFilter();` 31min ago. But yeah it was an easy improvement. Simply call that function.

Answer (score 1):

I used the attribute selector(`[filter][group]`) for this scenario,

```js
(function(){
  const selectedFilters = [];

  // [].slice.call => converts HTMLCollection to Array

  const yearFilters = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[filter][group="year"]'));
  const mediaFilters = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[filter][group="media"]'));
  const allFilters = yearFilters.concat(mediaFilters);
  
  const filterContents = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv'));

  // add click event to all filters
  allFilters.forEach((filter) => {
    filter.addEventListener('click', filterToggle);
  });
    
  function filterToggle() {
    const filter = this.getAttribute('filter');
    const group = this.getAttribute('group');

    resetMediaFilters();
    
    if(group === 'year') {
      resetYearFilters();
      mediaFilters[0].classList.add('active');
    }    

    this.classList.add('active');
    applyFilter();
  }
  
  function resetYearFilters() {
    yearFilters.forEach(filter => filter.classList.remove('active'));
  }
  
  function resetMediaFilters() {
    mediaFilters.forEach(filter => filter.classList.remove('active'));
  }
  
  function resetFilterContent() {
    filterContents.forEach(content => content.classList.remove('show'));
  }

  function applyFilter() {
    const selectedFilters = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[filter].active'))
                        .map(filter => filter.getAttribute('filter'));

// class starts with number is a invalid query selector, so using attribute selector for class
    const selector = ["filterDiv"].concat(selectedFilters).map(filter => '[class~="'+ filter +'"]').join('');
    
    resetFilterContent();
    
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(content => content.classList.add('show'));
  }
  
  // initialize
  applyFilter();
})();
```

```css
.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 37vw;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
     margin-right: 15px;
}




.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
}

.btn:hover {
}

.btn.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}



.content{
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:20px;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer" align="center" style="line-height: 20pt">
  <button class="btn active" filter="ShowAll" group="year">Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" filter="1950" group="year">1950</button>
  <button class="btn" filter="1960" group="year">1960</button>
  <button class="btn" filter="1970" group="year">1970</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="myBtnContainer" align="center" style="line-height: 20pt">
  <button class="btn active" filter="AllMedia" group="media">All Media</button>
  <button class="btn" filter="Movies" group="media">Movies</button>
  <button class="btn" filter="Music" group="media">Music</button>
  <button class="btn" filter="Newspapers" group="media">Newspapers</button>
</div>

<br><br>

 <div class="filterDiv AllMedia ShowAll 1950 Newspapers">
<div class="content">
  1950 Newspapers Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
</div>


 <div class="filterDiv AllMedia ShowAll 1960 Music">
<div class="content">
  1960 Music Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
</div>


 <div class="filterDiv AllMedia ShowAll 1960 Newspapers">
<div class="content">
  1960 Newspapers Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a document.getElementsByClassName() function in javascript that may help you here.
DOCS: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp
You can obtain an array of elements that match the class you want to target and you can then iterate over them to add/remove the hidden property or css class that makes them shown or hide.
The same can be applied for the buttons you want to make bolder.

Pseudocode example:

```
Click the RED filter
   Iterate over all elements on the page and
      If it has the RED class, make hidden property = false
      Otherwise, make hidden property = true
   Then, iterate over all buttons of type COLOUR
      If it's the RED button, add it the css class for btn_active
      Otherwise, remove the btn_active class
```

If the button clicked is ALL, the logic is a bit different but it's just a matter of playing with the if-elses.

Remember you also have the addClass and removeClass methods on each element. You don't have to convert the class list to an array of classes and iterate over them. It's much more simpler than that:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp

Comment: w3schools is still at this date a really bad learning resource. Also, is a pseudocode that suggests tons of if/else really the way to go?